# Как сжать код js?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как сжать код `js` ( удалить комментарии из кода, удалить переносы текста и так далее. ) может есть какой скрипт или программа которая будет работать на ноутбуке, без подключения к интернету.

Comment: https://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home

Comment: Для опросов есть гугл!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну для этого есть плагин `JSToolNpp` для `Notepad++` [ссылка на плагин](http://www.sunjw.us/jstoolnpp/), он удаляет комментарии и переносы и сжимает код, но все таки лучше сжимает код через онлайн компрессоры `js` кода, поищи в гугле **js compressor**.

Comment: Не обязательно использовать именно _онлайн_ компрессоры. Существует множество минификаторов, работающих без подключения к сети, например, uglify.js

Comment: Я просто имел в виду, что онлайн компрессоры лучше сжимают код. uglify.js я не пользовался. Спасибо обязательно попробую uglify.js.